# Evaluating a string of operations with standard python library no eval() function

Tags: python

I need a short function to return the answer to a string of multiplication/addition with pemdas. For example it should take "6*3+4" and return 22 or "7+3*10" and return 37. Ideally it could easily be changed to include division/subtraction.

I've tried doing this with index operations.

```
def pemdas(s):
    mult = "*"
    add = "+"
    mi = s.index(mult)
    res = int(s[mi-1])*int(s[mi+1])
    s = s[0:mi-1:]+s[mi+2::]
    s = s.replace(add,"")
    res = res + int(s)
    return res
```

Works with 1st test case but not the second. Unfortunately this fails with any double digit integer inputs. Is there a simple way of doing this without eval() and just the standard library?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()`, perhaps?

Comment: It already works with the second example?

Comment: when multiplying double digits sorry

Comment: how would i use ast.literal_eval()?

Comment: @jasonharper that wouldn't work. The whole point of `literal_eval` is to *__NOT__* allow these cases...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a simple parser:

```
import operator, re
ops = {'+':operator.add, '-':operator.sub, '*':operator.mul, '/':operator.truediv}
def _eval(tokens):
  a, *b = tokens
  if not b:
    return int(a)
  if b[0] in {'*', '/'}:
    while b and b[0] in {'*', '/'}:
       a = ops[b[0]](int(a), int(b[1]))
       b = b[2:]
    return a if not b else ops[b[0]](a, _eval(b[1:]))
  return ops[b[0]](int(a), _eval(b[1:]))

print(_eval(re.findall('\d+|[\+\*\-/]', "2*3*4+1")))
print(_eval(re.findall('\d+|[\+\*\-/]', "6+3*4")))
print(_eval(re.findall('\d+|[\+\*\-/]', "7*3+10")))
print(_eval(re.findall('\d+|[\+\*\-/]', "1+2*3*4+5")))
```

Output:

```
25
18
31
30
```

Edit: solution without `re` or `operator`:

```
def tokenize(stream):
  l, s = [], ''
  for i in stream:
     if i.isdigit():
       s += i
     else:
       l.append(s)
       l.append(i)
       s = ''
  return l+[s]

ops = {'+':lambda x, y:x+y, '-':lambda x, y:x-y, '*':lambda x, y:x*y, '/':lambda x, y:x/float(y)}
...
```

Now, to evaluate:

```
print(_eval(tokenize("6+3*4")))
```

Comment: Is it possible without operator or regex?

Comment: @c_a_l95 `operator` and `re` and modules from standard library, as you requested in the title of your question.

Comment: @c_a_l95 you can avoid `operator` by defining lambdas, for example: `ops = {'+': lambda x,y: x+y}`

Comment: @c_a_l95 As Sanyash pointed out, `re` and `operator` are from the standard library, but for a no-import solution, please see my recent edit.

Comment: Wow - this packs a lot of functionality into a few lines of code - nice job @Ajax1234! This seems to work for the scope that OP was asking about all right. It doesn't return the right answer for "1+2*3*4+5" for example, but I feel like "that guy" for even testing it. Your solution addresses the problem OP was asking about.

Comment: @WilfRosenbaum Thank you for your comment. I updated the solution to reflect the possible input you mentioned.

Comment: Oh - it wasn't my intention to prod you into modifying your implementation @Ajax1234. I think OP's original request was pretty underspecified (if that is a word) , and your solution met his criteria plus a whole lot more. Moreover you showed OP the right overall approach to the problem : tokenize the input and then interpret the string of tokens. His original strategy of using "index" to locate the operators in the input string was probably gonna cause him to lose his hair.

Comment: @WilfRosenbaum Actually, with your suggestions, my solution is much more readable than before (and more robust). Thank you again!